# Python Pandas - Passing a dataframe to other functions

Tags: python, performance, function, pandas, parameter-passing

EDIT - I have found a way to carry on the dataframe using dataframe.describe() - I have attached below the corrected version - This way the "DataExtract" is ran only once and then the dataframe is returned to be used in the Regression or ScatterPlot function.

```
import pandas as pd


# Extracting the data - Real query would be extracting X and Y from a SQL query and converting to a pandas frame
def DataExtract(Y, X):
    d = {Y: [1, 3, 3, 9, 5],
         X: [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(d)
    df = df.copy(deep=True)
    return df


# Build process using the data extracted in DataExtract
def Regression(df):
    from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
    df.describe()
    df.columns = ['Y', 'X']
    model = ols("Y ~ X", df).fit()
    print(model.summary())


# Plot a graph for a given dataframe
def ScatterPlot(df):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    df.describe()
    df.columns = ['Y', 'X']
    df.plot.scatter(x='X', y='Y')
    plt.show()

DataSet = DataExtract("a","b")
Regression(DataSet)
```

--
I have started to develop a few analytics functions and use Python at a beginner level mostly thanks to this site

I enclosed below a simplified example of how I currently compile my functions which are then called by the GUI, here we have a "DataExtract" function generating a frame and then either "Regression" or "ScatterPlot" depending on what the user want to do with the data.

The user would then call either "CombinedRegression" or "CombinedScatterPlot" to generate the output

```
    import pandas as pd

    #Extracting the data - Real query would be extracting X and Y from a SQL query and converting to a pandas frame
    def DataExtract(Y, X):
            d = {Y : [1, 3, 3, 9, 5],
                 X : [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]}
            df = pd.DataFrame(d)
            df = df.copy(deep=True)
            return df

    #Build process using the data extracted in DataExtract
    def Regression(df):
            from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
            df.columns = ['Y','X']
            model = ols("Y ~ X", df).fit()
            print(model.summary())

    #Plot a graph for a given dataframe
    def ScatterPlot(df):
            import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
            df.columns = ['Y', 'X']
            df.plot.scatter(x='X', y='Y')
            plt.show()

   def CombinedRegression(Y,X):
        Regression(DataExtract(Y, X))

    def CombinedScatterPlot(Y,X):
        ScatterPlot(DataExtract(Y, X))

    CombinedRegression("given Y","given X")

    CombinedScatterPlot("given Y","given X")
```

This building is not really efficient as I have to call the "Combined" functions in order to reach an output which ultimately forces me to generate the "DataExtract" function each time even though it is the same data used for both the Regression and the ScatterPlot Function. The GUI will emit the a and b slot to either function depending on which button is clicked

Ultimately what I would like to do is 1) Extract the data with the parameters a and b, and 2) Use the frame in either the regression or scatter plot or both given the command the user would give.

Thanks a lot for you help

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to pass around the dataframe `X` and the dataframe `Y`.

```
import pandas as pd

#Extracting the data - Real query would be extracting X and Y from a SQL query and converting to a pandas frame
def DataExtract(Y, X):
    d = {Y : [1, 3, 3, 9, 5],
             X : [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]}
    return df_X, df_Y

#Build process using the data extracted in DataExtract
def Regression(X, Y):
   from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
   model = ols("Y ~ X", df).fit()
   print(model.summary())

#Plot a graph for a given dataframe
def ScatterPlot(X, Y):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.scatter(x=X, y=Y)
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    X, Y = DataExtract()
    Regression(X, Y)
    Scatterplot(X, Y)
```

Comment: Hi Roelant, thank you for your answer. I have tried to run the sequence you wrote and ran into errors, even if I define 2 dataframes df_X, df_Y as pd.DataFrame they do not seem to pass on to either the Regression or ScatterPlot functions.

Answer (score 0):

All you really need to do is call the main function you want to run with the X, Y parameters you need to pass. Then, within those functions, pass it to the DataExtract function which will create and return your dataframe, and continue from there.

```
import pandas as pd

#Extracting the data - Real query would be extracting X and Y from a SQL query and converting to a pandas frame 
def DataExtract(Y, X): 
    d = {Y : [1, 3, 3, 9, 5], X : [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]} 
    df = pd.DataFrame(d)
    return df 

#Build process using the data extracted in DataExtract 
def Regression(X, Y):
    from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
    df = DataExtract(X, Y) 
    df.columns = ['Y','X']
    model = ols("Y ~ X", df).fit()
    print(model.summary()) 

#Plot a graph for a given dataframe 
def ScatterPlot(X, Y): 
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    df = DataExtract(X, Y)
    df.columns = ['Y', 'X']
    df.plot.scatter(x='X', y='Y')
    plt.show()
```

...and if the user wanted to do both, you could do something like:

```
def DoBoth(X, Y):
    ScatterPlot(X, Y)
    Regression(X, Y)
```

Comment: Hi pshep, thanks for your answer, your sequence runs perfectly however we would still have efficiency issues due to DataExtract running each time we run "Regression" or "ScatterPlot", I would like to isolate the "DataExtraction" if possible from the two other functions(The real "DataExtract" query is way more memory consuming) and run it once and then use the generated frame.

Comment: Not knowing exactly how the data is called, it might not be possible to keep the data frame in memory between your calls.  It might be a lot easier to save the data frame to file (or another database) and call upon it as I assume the extracted data would be considerably smaller than the full data set.

Comment: @MatNaomi - I just added another bit to run both functions if needed.